# DD command is not working as intended

Tags: command-line, ssd, dd

So i tried using this DD command to transfer my USB, ISO file og the Ubuntu download over to my SSD. I did this because i couldn't find my SSD but only my HDD before when i tried to install Ubuntu. As you see on the picture, i've runned this for 10 minutes without any results or even a Byte getting transfered. I cannot access the browser on the desktop, which is why the picture is there. I hope you can identify it enough.

Picture of my Terminal Emulation

[image]

Comment: Update! 30 minutes has now passed, still without any positive results... Shutting it down.

Comment: You're going to wipe out your NVMe SSD trying to use `dd` to copy an `.iso` that way. Hopefully the command has failed.

Comment: @wineunuuchs2Unix This would be the happy ending. My intentions are to wipe the ssd and only keep the installation file.

Comment: You want to turn a $500 NVMe SSD into a $10 installation USB pen drive?

Comment: @wineunuuchs2Unix no but to erase the content of the SSD to have the content of the USB pen drive.

Comment: Just use `gparted` to create partitions on the SSD. Then you can have 200 copies of the `.iso` on it if you're so inclined.

Comment: @WinEunuuchs2Unix The thing is, that i wannna boot my pc from the SSD, but i need to wipe the SSD first (Windows is still on it, and Ubuntu won't boot next to it  (That's what i have researched anyway)). Now getting the installation file over to the SSD while wiping it would be to kill two birds with one stone. Am wrong?
Asking because i seriously don't know.

Comment: @earthmeLon `dev/nvme0n1` is the entire `SSD`.  `dev/nvme0n1p1` would be the first partition.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- You *can* install Ubuntu alongside Windows (at least in normal drives)
- If you clone a drive, the previous partition table, file system and some of the content will be overwritten. You will not see it, so only if you want to erase all traces because of security reasons, you need to wipe the whole drive
- Seeing your picture, I think your command line is bad, after `pv` you should redirect to the target device, not pipe via `sudo`.

  - It is easier to do after `sudo -i` with `dd` and `pv`, but it is *risky*. A minor typing error is enough to damage valuable data in a device (drive), that you did not intend to touch.
  - It is safer (and easy) to use [**`mkusb-dus`**](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/mkusb), which can clone from a device to another device. There is a final checkpoint, that helps you check once again, that you will write to the intended device, and not another device. After installing mkusb, assuming the source device `/dev/sdb`, you run

    ```
    dus /dev/sdb
    ```

    and you will be guided via menus to select the correct target device.

Comment: "If you clone a drive, the previous partition table, file system and some of the content will be overwritten"
But will i be able to boot from it then? And thanks for an answer mate.

Comment: An Ubuntu (or Ubuntu community flavour) iso file will make a bootable drive, when cloned to a mass storage device (USB pendrive, memory card, HDD, SSD ...) and DVD disk. 64-bit systems can boot in BIOS (legacy) mode as well as in UEFI mode. But you will destroy the previous system, so if you want to keep Windows, you had better do something else than you ask for, for example shrink the Windows partition (using Windows tools), clone to a USB pendrive, boot from it and install Ubuntu alongside Windows (in the unallocaded space created, when you shrank Windows).

Comment: i don't wanna save anything from the last, having it dosen't bother me. But neither will it stand in the way so erasing it is no problem for me. i just cloned the ISO file over to my SSD, and tried to boot from it. only black screen apeared until i shutted down my desktop and booted from the USB again. I have no idea how to make my SSD bootable.

Comment: Please tell us about your computer: brand name and model and also about your graphics chip/card, brand name and model. Are you sure that your computer is really trying to boot from the SSD? Can you boot from an external drive (typically a USB pendrive)? -- There is another problem with cloning. In order to work (well), the physical sectors of the source and target should be the same. Use `sudo parted -ls` to find the physical sector sizes.

Comment: I've built the computer myself.
Processor: intel core i5 8600k coffee lake.
Graphic card: Nvidia Geforce gtx 1070 ti.
HDD: seagate barracuda 2 TB.
SDD: Force MP500 120 GB.
Tell me if other parts are needed.

I go to the BIOS whenever i boot. Tapping on the SSD to make it boot. (Which always ends in failure with Ubuntu). Instead i click on the USB FLASH holding the ISO file that i have downloaded from my laptop. The ISO file does not seem to be the problem. -- Physical sectors are both 512B/512B.

Comment: You may have problems with the nvidia card. The first step is to use the [boot option](http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2230389&p=13370808#post13370808) `nomodeset` (or unplug it and use the built-in graphics of the i5 CPU as a starting point).

Comment: Tried unplugging the graphic card. No changed result. But i have noticed that whenever i start my computer it keeps starting up and then shutting down after 3 seconds repeating this process over and over. I then hold the power button turning it off. and turn it on to get the "fail accured" BIOS screen.

Comment: This seems to be a problem that occurs before Ubuntu is started. What drives are connected or can be connected? Internal HDD, external HDD (via eSATA or USB), memory card (via PCI or USB), DVD (via SATA or USB)? Can you try to boot some other way via one of the other alternatives? Can you try with another USB pendrive (other brand name or model), a pendrive that you know works in another computer?

Comment: I'm glad you made it work. Congratulations :-)

Comment: Yes! thanks for learning me to use the DD command =D