# Installation file is not working

Tags: system-installation

So i have wanted to install Ubuntu from my new pc. Nothing is on the SSD yet. But i clicked "something else" in the installation instead of "erase disk and install Ubuntu" because my SSD wouldn't show up in there. In the "something else" i made the partitions myself as i was following a youtube video. I made the root "/", the EFI and the SWAP, but it wouldn't install as shown on the pictures. Pls help me understand.

Different from the from the other "help-article" because the guy can actually find his HDD under the "erase disk and install Ubuntu" were i can't.

[image: Image 1]

[image: Image 2]

[image: Image 3]

EDIT: Picture of Gparted:

[image]

Comment: @user68186 he is using MBR. Partition 1 is primary, the second primary partition (not shown in the pictures) is extended and contains partitions 5 and 6. 3 and 4 are not used because theses would refer to primary partitions (there can be 4 primary partitions using MBR). That is AFAIK the standard layout when installing Ubuntu. Pottepl4nt3n1055, where did you boot the installer from?

Comment: @Danzel i booted it from a USB FLASH DRIVE. it is an ISO file which i downloaded from their own website

Comment: @danzel the MBR partition scheme makes sense. I have not used the MBR for a while now and forgotten about it. In that case, the ESP needs to be a primary partition.   I'd make ESP partition 2 not 6. But that may not solve the problem. Since this is an UEFI system (needs ESP partition) it may be better to start over making the SSD a GPT system.

Comment: @User68186 And how do i do that? Making it a GPT System*

Comment: Consider accepting my answer as the correct one by clicking on the green check mark on the left margin next to the answer. This will help others.

Answer (score 1):

## I think I figured out your problem

**The Gparted screenshot is strange!** The file system shows iso9660, a format for data DVD. The "key" means it is mounted. This makes me think you are somehow using the SSD as the Live DVD (or media). Based on [DD command is not working as intended](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1036634/dd-command-is-not-working-as-intended) you have transferred the ISO image to the SSD and now you are booting from the Live ISO image from the SSD. Based on the picture you posted in the other question, your Live USB was `/dev/sdb` when you copied it into the SSD.

**Make sure you boot from the flash drive not the SSD.**

**Next you need to erase the ISO image from the SSD and setup Guided Partition Table (GPT):**

Your system has UEFI, the newer kind of BIOS. You are booting in the new UEFI mode, not in legacy BIOS mode. UEFI expects the GPT (Guided Partition Table) but you have setup your SSD with MBR (Master Boot Record).

To change the partition table of the SSD you will have to start from scratch. **This will erase all the data and partitions in the SSD.**

**Step 1:** Boot from the Live USB flash drive and choose "Try Ubuntu without installing".

**Step 2:** Open Gparted and select the SSD from the drop-down menu at the top right corner. In this image below it says `/dev/sdc`. Yours should say `/dev/nvme0n1`.

**Step 3:** Click on the **Device > Create Partition Table...** from the top menu. A sub-window will pop up:

[image]

**Step 4:**  Change the Type from `msdos` to `gpt` as shown in the picture above.

**Step 5:** Click on the <kbd>Apply</kbd> button to create the new Guided Partition Table.

The following steps are not necessary. The Ubuntu installation should recognize the SSD now and you should be able to use "erase disk and install Ubuntu".

Since you are here, you may as well create the partitions needed, the `EFI` partition and the root filesystem partition `/`. Ubuntu 18.04 uses swap files by default. So you don't need to create the `swap` partition.

The EFI partition must be a primary partition formatted FAT32 and should have the **esp** and **boot** flags set. You can select these flags from within Gparted.

The `/` partition can be formatted `ext4`.

Hope this helps

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/77590/discussion-on-answer-by-user68186-installation-file-is-not-working).