# 18.04 Install constantly fails at various levels – Gigabyte 970A-DS3P

Tags: system-installation, 18.04

I have been trying to install 18.04 on a brand-new put-together system for the past week and getting to various levels into the install but the system will lock-up (‘stall’ a better word?).  Have tried an 18.04 DVD, 16.04 DVD (the latter works fine on the several Ubuntu installs).  (Disk’s self-check option reports is good.)  Know to leave things for a while so will let things go for 15-20 minutes.  Have Googled and looked through here to try to figure out what to do.

Sometimes just see the Ubuntu screen with the dots blinking and that’s all – usually advances to allow various stages of installation.  Have gotten to the install the system files step and downloading files (yea!!) but then when I came back it indicated there was a problem with the installation.

Also tried ‘mini.iso’ on a thumbdrive – this is the one I seem to get the furthest but still no completion.  Figured maybe my system needed something not on the DVD.

Have ‘noticed’ USB 2..0 seems to shut off: the mouse’s LED shuts off and no longer works; the keyboard also ‘dies’.  Tried a new-in-box mouse and keyboard – nope.  Old keyboard and mouse on the USB 3.0 ports work fine, though occasionally when the system locks up also dies.

Motherboard :   Gigabyte 970A-DS3P
CPU:            AMD FX-8320 8-core  @ 3500 MHz
Memory:     32 GB
Graphics card:  XFX AMD Radeon R7 250
PSU:            EVGA 750W 
SDD     Crucial CT275MX3    275 GB
HDD     Western Digital WD30EFRX-68E    3.0 TB+

Have attempted to use the installed BluRay./DVD/CD (RW) for the disc; thought maybe something didn’t like BR so tried an external DVD (on USB 3.0); thought maybe there was something missing because the USB 2.0 ports stop working.

A random grab of error messages, over various install attempts:

```
Couldn’t get size
MODSIGN: Couldn’t get UEFI db listings
Invalid PCI ROM number      expecting 0xaa55, got 0xde3c
USB 4-1  and 4-2 errors (for USB 2.0??)

error -32    unable to enumerate USB device

Text screen: USB errors,   G_UDEV_IS_DEVICE (device) failed
```

Just locked up at the screen that says “Live session user”

Gparted 0.31.0-1-amd64
    While loading errors re: USB 6  (finally loaded and both USB 2 and 3 mice worked)
    Eventually loaded; followed instructions of (NZXT -4a)  [Installation file is not working](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1037009/installation-file-is-not-working/1037050#1037050)
Switched SDD from msdos to gpt
(Gparted disc took a while to load; also Desktop’s Exit took several minutes to respond.  Neither seems right.)   Now even worse – log screen with series of traces

picture of screen  at https://pastebin.com/ydjXiQJt  -- hopefully!
No idea if that has anything helpful.

So there’s something wrong somewhere; I’ve run out of ideas on what I can so and so am requesting assistance

TIA!  Barry

---

Edited next morning (June 16, 2018):
Hi Folks!

Have done a little research.  Appears the ‘USB 3.0 works but USB 2.0’ doesn’t can be somewhat fixed from this thread:
    https://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2188370   “GA-970A-DS3P revision 1 no usb 3.0”

Main difference is he has a working system and mine won’t even install.  I did do a bit of experimenting:  before installing I modified the command line to   iommu=soft   quiet splash  (added ‘iommu=soft’ before ‘quiet’).  (I also enabled iommu in UEFI.)  Appears both USB 2 and 3 now work, or at least both mice have their LEDs on and both keyboards with do a NumLock toggle.   Silly thing is just sitting there; eventually this popped up on the screen:

```
Couldn’t get size: 0x800000000000000e
MODSIGN: Couldn’t get UEFU db list
Couldn’t get size 0x8000000000000000e
radeon 0000:04:00.0: Invalid PCI header signature: expecting 0x1155, got 0xde3c
```

First line time = 14.239766, last line = 14.407510.  Run time since boot, right?  Took a lot longer to appear than fourteen seconds.  Probably more important the error messages.

DVD kept blinking away for maybe a minute or two more and then stopped, no updates to screen.  Has been probably a half-hour; system appears to be alive (or at least mice on and can toggle NumLock) but the cursor is not blinking.

Thanks! Barry

Comment: When I download and install 18.04,  it works properly. Go back to basics: Check your hashes on the .iso download. Check your DVD burn. Check your thumbdrive for proper function (they wear out).

Comment: Before I install on an unknown/untrusted system; I run memtest & like tools a few days (*varies on intended role*) to verify the hardware is reliable....

Comment: GIGABYTE GA-970A-DS3 motherboard not working with 64 bit kernel - IOMMU GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX="iommu=soft" http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2111223&page=5 [SOLVED] GA-970A-DS3P revision 1 no usb 3.0
http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2188370 Do not know AMD, but if Ryzen, you may also need newer kernels than in current distributions. Raven Ridge With The Ryzen 5 2400G On Mesa 18.2 + Linux 4.17 Is Finally Stable MSI B350M GAMING PRO
https://www.phoronix.com/scan.php?page=article&item=ryzen-2400g-may&num=1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

(I should update better!) The problem was a faulty RAM stick.  Finally tried MemTest -- the default option did not detect a problem but the F2 option did.

Answer (score 0):

Well I screwed something up: wanted to post individual replies but wouldn't let me plus a limited number of characters.  Guess this will have to work:

To User535733:
Going back to basics is always a good starting point when jumping into the middle to troubleshoot isn’t working!  I had done the ‘check the disk for being right’ (on the initial ‘try/install/memtest’ page) and that passed.  Assumed (uh-huh!!) that tested disc integrity but apparently not.  Installed GtkHash.  Command line (only because I was at Terminal to install and just delete part of the commandline):

```
MD5:        129292a182136a35e1f89c586dbac2e2    (matches online)
SHA1:       f373c0aec6162cdba76ee9084e695866a15e441a    (matches online)
SHA256: a55353d837cbf7bc006cf49eeff05ae5044e757498e30643a9199b9a25bc9a34    (matches online)
```

OK, apparently the ISO is fine and also the DVD.

The thumbrive was an ‘alternative attempt’ and had ‘mini.iso’ on it, not the full Ubuntu_18.04.ISO.  My thinking was maybe the DVD didn’t have something included and so try a different method.

---

To Guiverc:
But we want it now!     That and other shortcuts like not verifying file integrity are probably the worst thing being done; at least I did do the Check Disk step.  I had also checked   in UEFI Configuration all of the memory was being seen and CPU cores were running normally.  At least I performed a few verifications.

---

To OldFred:
Ah! This looks like a ‘chunky beef stew of information’!  Thanks!  Will look into those later and get back to you.

In the interim have done two or three installation attempts which failed.  One thing that seems odd to me is all of the attempts have failed at different levels: some fail almost immediately, some somewhat close to completion, most somewhere in the middle.  I don’t understand most of the errors scrolling to the screen though Googling there seems to be a consistency with a potential problem with Secure Boot Mode.  No option mentioned in the manual; on-line there is something for Windows 8 install.  Not so sure I want to go on that pathway.

Did regress a bit and retried the 16.04 DVD – it installed!!    Right now USB 3 isn’t working – I can deal with that for now: at least don’t have a semi-expensive box mocking me.  No idea what the difference between 18.04 and 16.04 is.    Have seen instructions on how upgrade to 18.04 so may try that; will look at your information first.

Thanks again!
Barry

---

Updated information:

Hi OldFred!

Finally getting to experiment and reply: busy-ish weekend.  Appears the first two links are essentially the same and seem to have resolved the USB and NIC issues here.  (Thanks!)  I did backtrack: 18.04 simply refused to install here: can do anything from barely start the installation and stall/hang/whatever to almost making it to the end and hangs/an error pops up.  The system, gateway, hubs, etc., are on UPSs: it gets noisy when the power goes out!

Did go back to 16.04. did the IOMMU steps in your suggestion, and that now allows both the USB 2.0 and 3.0 mice and keyboards to work.

I did see this in one of the forums:

> I don't think I'd recommend this MB series to a novice doing his/her own Ubuntu installation. Given that the fix requires googling the right terms to find this thread or a similar one, modifying the BIOS settings, editing a text configuration file and mucking around a little on the command line, it might sort of spoil the "it just works" experience of installing and using Ubuntu.

I’ll just say “I agree!”.  I was more or less shocked when the installation failed; but-but-but they’ve always worked since I started with 10.10.  Good news is it looks like quite a few have this motherboard so we can help each other and people like you and others are willing to also assist.

As for the AMD Ryzen link – that one went over my head but I don’t think I have one.  From the 16.04 Settings > Details:
    Processor   AMD FX-8320 Eight-core Processor x8

At this point I’m not sure what to do.  LIS I backed up a little and have 16.04 installed (along with its updates).  Firefox crashes but that’s a separate issue (have submitted a few reports to them).  Haven’t had too much time to play.  Half-thinking to install VirtualBox (Oracle’s version) to install XP on it (like I do on the machine I’m using currently) and probably and experimental VM (virtual machine) Ubuntu 16.04 as well as see what a VM18.04 does.

Barry